# Is it possible to embed a SharePoint Calendar into a non-SharePoint website?

Tags: sharepoint, web, calendar

I am trying to find out if there is a way to put a SharePoint Calendar into a normal web-page that will update whenever the SharePoint Calendar is updated. Does anyone know if it's possible?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint has some standard web services which you can use to access data stored in the SharePoint site.

Look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221152136/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx) for an example of how to use these with at calendar

But be aware that the standard SharePoint web services will not allow you to expand recurring events.